# Тире в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Попалось в тексте выражение "дети (—) цветы жизни" без тире. Это ошибка или тут действительно не нужно тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тире нужно, т.к. можно сказать:"Дети - ЭТО цветы жизни."

Answer (score 0):

Подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в именительном падеже, поэтому ставится тире.